# Convert NSString to NSDate and timeZone?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Ive been racking my brains with no luck. Could someone please tell my how i would convert this string:

```
 NSString *dateTimeStr =[[self.responseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"date_time"];
```

**2014-04-13T17:00:00+11:0**

into a `NSDate`? and time format ?

how can i covert this date into time format ?

here is my code:

```
NSString *dateTimeStr =[[self.responseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"date_time"];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateTimeStr];

NSLog(@"date %@", date);

NSTimeInterval seconds = [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
```

in console

```
NSLog(@"seconds==> %f", seconds);
```

i have time in miliseconds then how can i take out `minutes/hours/` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559912/date-time-parsing-in-ios-how-to-deal-or-not-deal-with-timezones

Comment: you mean you need to convert string to date, instead of date to timeformat.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya i need to convert my string to timeFormat, actually i want to take difference between my current time and json response nsstring so i can get the result in mins/hours like this 1hour ago

Comment: @AnoopVaidya i want to take sec/min/hour from that string.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *dateString = @"2014-04-13T17:00:00+11:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
                                    components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit
                                    fromDate:date];

NSInteger year = [dateComponents year];
NSInteger month = [dateComponents month];
NSInteger day = [dateComponents day];
```